# SQL uncondensing data / generating more rows containing similar data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data which is very variable in it's update frequency (doesn't change for ages, then changes very often).

I sample it according to a schedule I create and end up with the table below:

| periodStart | periodEnd | variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2019 00:06 | 01/10/2019 01:00 | 0.61 |
| 01/10/2019 01:00 | 01/10/2019 02:00 | 0.61 |
| 01/10/2019 02:00 | 01/10/2019 03:00 | 0.61 |
| 01/10/2019 03:00 | 01/10/2019 04:00 | 0.61 |
| 01/10/2019 04:00 | 01/10/2019 05:00 | 0.61 |
| 01/10/2019 05:00 | 01/10/2019 06:00 | 0.61 |
| 01/10/2019 06:00 | 01/10/2019 07:00 | 0.61 |
| 01/10/2019 07:00 | 01/10/2019 08:00 | 0.61 |
| 01/10/2019 08:00 | 01/10/2019 09:00 | 0.59 |
| 01/10/2019 09:00 | 01/10/2019 10:00 | 0.59 |
| 01/10/2019 10:00 | 01/10/2019 11:00 | 0.59 |
| 01/10/2019 11:00 | 01/10/2019 12:00 | 0.58 |

I am trying to condense the database so stored it the alternative form below.  I also need to retain access to the original sampling timestamps (periodStart and periodEnd), so created 'samplingInterval'.  Using this you can determine all original periodStart and periodEnd timestamps from the new periodStart and periodEnd.

| periodStart | periodEnd | samplingInterval(mins) | variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2019 00:06 | 01/10/2019 01:00 | 54 | 0.61 |
| 01/10/2019 01:00 | 01/10/2019 08:00 | 60 | 0.61 |
| 01/10/2019 08:00 | 01/10/2019 11:00 | 60 | 0.59 |
| 01/10/2019 11:00 | 01/10/2019 12:00 | 60 | 0.58 |

The issue I am having is writing a query to SELECT the table in the original form from it's condensed form.  I'm comfortable writing a query using a SQL variable, thinking I could use a loop (in a stored procedure, which is less than ideal) but I just don't know how to output the row without advancing to the next row.  Is it possible?  Should I be approaching it differently?

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question

Comment: apologies and thanks for pointer @nbk

Comment: I think that the second row value of `periodEnd` in the condensed table should be `01/10/2019 08:00`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `Recursive Query` as the following:

```
With recursive cte as
(
  select periodStart st, 
  adddate(periodStart , interval samplingInterval minute) en
  ,periodEnd,variable,samplingInterval si
  From condensed
  Union All
  select adddate(st, interval si minute), 
  adddate(en, interval si minute),
  periodEnd,variable,si from cte
  where adddate(st , interval si minute)<periodEnd
)
select st as periodStart,en as periodEnd,variable  from cte order by st;
```

See a deom from [***db-fiddle***](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u2HEYC1wCLe9LhLcg5VRPk/0).

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I had not heard of a recursive CTE, but that's probably partly because I am using MySql 5.7, which does not seem to support them. I might have to upgrade, which would also require an O/S upgrade because I am still using win7.